# How to answer dial prompts in Twilio client?

Tags: twilio

After reading and rereading the docs on the [Twilio Client JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) I can't figure out how to answer dial prompts from the Twilio-JS client. I used the [demo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart#download) to fashion an outbound call client, where I can call from the browser to whichever number I need, and it's useful for calling people in sequence from my computer.

There are some times when I need to call a business that runs me through prompts before someone answers. Where are the docs for handling in-call prompts? I'm not even sure the right terms to be asking. Basically, if I call a number from the in-browser client and the remote end says, "Press 1 for English", how can I dial 1?

**Edit:**

Thank you for the answer. Hoping that maybe it could be helpful to someone, here's the dialpad I made for testing the `sendDigits()` method. Make sure your connection variable is accessible in the namespace where you bind your buttons.

html:

```
<table id="keypad">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>*</td><td>0</td><td>#</td></tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#keypad{
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border: wheat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#keypad td{
    width:20px;
    height:30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(5,5,5,.7);
}

#keypad td:hover{
    background-color: rgba(5,5,5,.3);
}
```

js

```
// Bind button to make dial an digit
var dialPadButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
for(i=0;i<dialPadButtons.length;i++){
    dialPadButtons[i].onclick = function(){
        connection.sendDigits(this.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To answer those prompts you need to be able to send [DTMF tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling). The Twilio Client JS has this built in for you to build with. You will need to build your interface for it though.

The method you are looking for is [`connection.sendDigits(digits)`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#sendDigits). You can send multiple digits at a time or one per key press.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed and very helpful.

Comment: Excellent! Hope the rest of your app goes well.